# pre-receive git hook to reject force but allow force-with-lease push

Tags: git

Is it possible to create a server-side pre-receive git hook to reject push with `--force` but not reject push with `--force-with-lease`?

Comment: I don't think any git hooks (server *or* client-side) receive the command line arguments like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that because they look identical to the server.

The way a Git ref update works is that the client asks the server to update a given ref from an old value to a new value.  On the server side, Git can tell if the old value is an ancestor of the new value (a regular push) or not (a force push), and act accordingly.  However, in either case, the old value must match the current value on the server; if it does not, the ref update will fail, because that means that you've raced with someone else that's pushing.

In most cases, when you do a ref update with `--force`, the old value is whatever the server advertised in its ref advertisement.  What `--force-with-lease` does is it asks Git to specify the old value not from what the server has advertised, but from the remote tracking branch or the value specified by the user.  However, the server doesn't know that the user has specified this option.  All it knows is whether the old value matches (which is always required) and whether it's a parent of the new value (in which case it's a force push).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer you gave. 
I was actually wondering about the GitHub rule "Require linear history". If this rule is active, then most likely the "Allow force pushes" rule should be enabled as well. But in case several people are working on a branch, there is a risk of losing commits. This risk is greatly reduced if everyone uses "force-with-lease". That's why I started looking into whether or not it's technically possible to implement this check at all.
*Very happy to receive a response from a GitHub member and a git contributor.

Comment: When I work like that, I usually push in a bunch of squash or fixup commits (`git commit --squash` and `git commif --fixup`) and then talk to colleagues before I squash them.  Some teams might have a dedicated person do a squash every couple of days.  But I agree that's a tricky situation, and it's easy to mess up.